# Any solution to save whole sandbox per branch in git, including ignored files?

Tags: git

I have a problem working efficiently with git in a specific projet, and I'm looking for a potential solution to stay effective.

Here is my problem:

For a given project I frequently need to change from a work branch to another work branch, re-compile the code to test something, and go back to my previous branch. When compiling, a lot of compilation results are generated in folders ignored by git (as usual).

It's not something that is unusual really, but it gets more complicated in my specific project due to the following reasons:

- The compilation time is important (like 45 minutes)
- The whole sandbox must be erased when we switch from one branch to another because our compilation solution is not smart enough to correctly track differences between source files (it's a C++ project ;(, those things never really work in that language)

So when I switch from my "current" work branch to another branch I have no other choice than erasing all my current compilation results, launch the compilation in that other branch (no way around that, it will effectively take me 45 minutes in all cases) then go back to my initial branch and *re-compile again* because I lost my initial compilation results in the process.

One "simple" possible solution to not loose my sandbox is to just work with multiple different clones. But it's not very convenient because we have quite a lot of binary files stored in git LFS that will then need to be duplicated on my file system. And I'm running a bit low on storage space... so not very good either.

So, what I would envision as a possible solution:

Theoretically it wouldn't be very difficult to have a mechanism that just saves all my compilation results (in this case, just all ignored files in the project) whenever I change from one branch to another. In that case, when I switch branch, instead of having to erase my compilation results it would just save them and restore them later.

Yeah I know there is `git stash` that could more or less do the work. But using directly git stash is not that convenient in this workflow for multiple reasons (notably: it's not really meant to save ignored files, it's a bit more complex to use it for that, and it necessitates quite a lot of manual interactions that shouldn't be messed to make it work).

I could somehow imagine some kind of script, possibly relying on hooks, that put all the ignored files aside whenever a checkout on a new branch occurs, detect if the targeted branch already had ignored file in its internal database, and restore those ignored files if that's the case.

The reason I post this question is to know if some git extension already does that more or less. So, do you know something like that ?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

That's already explained in the question.

Comment: I've had the same issues and just had to bite the bullet. `ccache` can help a little, though. I never tried this myself, but somehow set build directories to `obj-<revision-hash>`, but then you have the problem of lots of `obj-<hash>` directories clogging up your system...

Comment: Try `git worktree`. `git clone --reference-if-able=<path/to/existing/repo>` is another option.

Comment: @KenY-N : yeah no, I really definitively dropped the idea of trying to fix that problem on the compiler level. I'm just only looking for ways to work on the git level now.

Comment: @ElpieKay : didn't know about `git worktree`. This seems really interesting, I'm gonna try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not really performing the same way that was imagined by the author, [`git worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) can be a solution for the described problem.

The purpose of that standard git feature is to checkout other branches in new folders, thus *not* altering the current sandbox. While there are multiple copies of the code on the file system this still save disk space as it allows to maintain a single git history (and, in the case of git LFS usage, a single cache of LFS objects).